# Representation power of State Space Models

Tags: state-space-models

We can represent subclass of linear time invariant (LTI) systems with State Space Representation:

$$\dot X = AX + BU,$$
$$Y = CX + DU.$$

Also, nonlinear systems are formulated with generalized State Space Representation where the functions could be nonlinear:

$$\dot X=f(X,U,t),$$
$$Y = g(X,U,t).$$

The question is, what is their representation power? Can we formulate **any** system in State Space Model?

Comment: What is LTI? Also, how do you define *representation power*; does it reflect the generality of representation (how large the variety of processes representable in this way is)?

Comment: LTI is linear time invariant.
I mean can we represent all linear time invariant systems in this representation?
How about nonlinear systems?